# Unable to load pandas and boto3 python 3.11

Tags: python, pandas, boto3

Doing a simple test script..

```
import boto3
import pandas as pd

def main():
    print(hello)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get the following error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bgibson/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/pandastest.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/Users/bgibson/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(_dependency)
  File "/Users/bgibson/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
    from . import random
  File "/Users/bgibson/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/random/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import _pickle
  File "/Users/bgibson/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/numpy/random/_pickle.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .mtrand import RandomState
  File "mtrand.pyx", line 1, in init numpy.random.mtrand
  File "bit_generator.pyx", line 38, in init numpy.random.bit_generator
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/secrets.py", line 19, in <module>
    getsecrets = get_secrets(client)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/secrets.py", line 9, in get_secrets
    value = client.list_secrets(MaxResults=50)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 534, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 959, in _make_api_call
    http, parsed_response = self._make_request(
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 982, in _make_request
    return self._endpoint.make_request(operation_model, request_dict)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 119, in make_request
    return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 198, in _send_request
    request = self.create_request(request_dict, operation_model)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 134, in create_request
    self._event_emitter.emit(
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 412, in emit
    return self._emitter.emit(aliased_event_name, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 256, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 239, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 105, in handler
    return self.sign(operation_name, request)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/signers.py", line 189, in sign
    auth.add_auth(request)
  File "/Users/user/PycharmProjects/Cloud/cloud/lib/python3.11/site-packages/botocore/crt/auth.py", line 55, in add_auth
    raise NoCredentialsError()
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If I remove boto3 entirely I get an error "numpy: No module named 'boto3'
" eventhough I'm not trying to import it.

I only see that package reference in a couple of tests in the package(conftest and test_network)

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out.  I had a different python script with a name of secrets.py that was getting called instead of the proper package.  Presumably because it had a name of secrets as well.